# having difficulty with making a list of 0's in 2 or more dimension

Tags: python, list

I wanna make a 2D list, exemple:

```
a = [[0],[0]]
```

but I dont know how many 0's and [0]'s there will be. I tried:

```
a = [0]*1  #there could be other integer there
a = [a]*2

print a
[[0],[0]]
```

it output what I want and I can change the number of 0's but if I do:

```
a[0][0] += 1

print a
[[1],[1]]
```

it changes all the values. if I manually write it:

```
a = [[0],[0]]
a[0][0] += 1

print a
[[1],[0]]
```

it works correctly. I know why it does that, "a" isnt a variable, its a pointer. and I just create new pointer looking at the same 0's so when I change one they all change but how do I create a list of list of 0's with freedom of choosing the amount of 0's without making all the pointers looking at the same 0's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list comprehension will give you the proper behavior since it creates a new list for each element:

```
a = [[0] for i in range(2)]
```